# Clip image by each feature in a FeatureCollection with Google Earth Engine

Tags: export, google-earth-engine

I have a raster image `myRaster` (ee.Image) and a FeatureCollection `indexGrid` which contains a polygon grid with a single attribute `index` (string).

My goal is to split the image by polygons in a FeatureCollection and export each tile to Drive. The best thing I came up with follows, but it doesn't work:

```js
var grid_export = function(feature){
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image: myRaster,
  description: 'part_' + feature.get('index'),
  folder: 'dst',
  scale: 30,
  region: feature.geometry()
  });
  return null;
};

indexGrid.map(grid_export);
```

Comment: There is a package for the Python API that has a function called `exportByFeat` (https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools) that does exaclty what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the FeatureCollection and start a export for each feature. In Python you can start all the exports directly,  inside the code editor you would need to click on each task.

A client side loop is usually not recommended in GEE. As is calling `.getInfo()`. However, I don't know of any other way to start multiple exports.

Here's an example in JavaScript for the code editor:

```js
for(var f=0; f<grid_export.length; f++) {
  var feature = ee.Feature(grid_export[f]);

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: myRaster.clip(feature.geometry()),
    description: 'part_' + feature.get('index').getInfo(),
    folder: 'dst',
    scale: 30,
    region: feature.geometry()
  });
}
```